# COM Basic links

Tags: c#, c++, com, winapi, visual-c++

folks can you provide me the tutorial link or .pdf for learning basic COM?.
i do google it.. still i recommend answers of stackoverflow so please pass me..

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some of my better bookmarks:

- [Wikipedia - Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)
- [Introduction to COM - What It Is and How to Use It.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx)
- [Introduction to COM Part II - Behind the Scenes of a COM Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro2.aspx)
- [Finally Understanding COM After Changing a Light Bulb](http://www.moserware.com/2008/01/finally-understanding-com-after.html)
- [Introduction to COM](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ArcGISDevHelp/DevelopmentEnvs/COM/IntroToCOM.htm)
- [MSDN - Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877981(loband).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Though you have asked for links, I would recommend you the book: [Inside COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572313498) by Dale Rogerson.

Comment: Essential COM by Don Box often gets recommended on this subject? Any opinion on this book? http://www.amazon.com/Essential-COM-Don-Box/dp/0201634465

Answer (score 2):

[Step by Step COM Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Essential COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465) by Don Box. He explains things from the bottom up, and gives you the **Why** as well as the **How**

Answer (score 1):

Another good link for [COM](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/COM.htm) that has a lot of information. I used this one to help me write an application in C++ that uses office automation.